# How to implement JWT token in .net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, jwt

I've been battling for a few hours with this, and can't seem to track down why all my calls to my `[Authorize]` enabled endpoints are failing with a 401.

In my .Net Core 2.2 Web API project, in Startup.cs, I have setup my authentication:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
            Configuration.Bind(nameof(jwtSettings), jwtSettings);
            services.AddSingleton(jwtSettings);

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            // Add the JWT Bearer token configuration
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("craigcraigcraigcraigcraigcraig")),//jwtSettings.Secret)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My Backend", Version = "v1" });
                var security = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    {"Bearer", new string[0]}
                };
                x.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorisation header using the bearer scheme",
                    Name = "Authorisation",
                    In = "header",
                    Type = "apiKey"
                });
                x.AddSecurityRequirement(security);

            });
        }
```

- Note, I hard coded my key, as I wasn't sure if maybe that was the issue.

Then, in configure, I am telling my app to `UseAuthentication` as well as making sure Swagger knows that I'll need some Authorisation help.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            // This is getting the seetings from a 'SwaggerOptions' section within appSettings.[Env].json, and bind that data to the SwaggerOptions class.
            var swaggerOptions = new Options.SwaggerOptions();
            Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Options.SwaggerOptions)).Bind(swaggerOptions);

            app.UseSwagger(option => { option.RouteTemplate = swaggerOptions.JsonRoute; });
            app.UseSwaggerUI(option => { option.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerOptions.UiEndpoint, swaggerOptions.Description); });


            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I have an endpoint which recieves a username and password. I do some checks and if the username and password are good, I generate a token:

```
private string GenerateToken(UserDto user)
        {
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("craigcraigcraigcraigcraigcraig");// config.GetSection("JwtSettings").GetSection("Secret").Value);
            var singingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(key);

           var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, user.Firstname),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName, user.Surname),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                        new Claim("id", user.Id.ToString())
                    }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(singingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

This token gets back to my Swagger front end and looks OK.

The response I get in swagger:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtZUBoZXJlLmNvbSIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJDcmFpZyIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiU21pdGgiLCJqdGkiOiI2ZWJkYjk4MC1iZWM0LTQzMTctOTkwYy1kN2Q3Mzk4MmY3Y2QiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1lQGhlcmUuY29tIiwiaWQiOiIzMjA3YWZkOC1kMTU5LTQwNTgtYmVlNS1kZmRmYzBhYzBlODgiLCJuYmYiOjE1NjM4NzI4ODYsImV4cCI6MTU2Mzg4MDA4NiwiaWF0IjoxNTYzODcyODg2fQ.FGuc5qU-3QoIJBodYf6yi3Wi9Q9RS2kdp0NHaCrplaY"
}
```

I validate this in jwt.ms:

[image]

So at this point, I have generated a valid JWT (I think).

I have a test endpoint. I 'Authorize' in Swagger (Click Authorise, type 'Bearer' and paste token.

When I execute my 'Autorize' endpoint, I get this back

> curl -X GET "https://localhost:44370/api/accounts" -H "accept:
>   application/json" -H "Authorisation: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtZUBoZXJlLmNvbSIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJDcmFpZyIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiU21pdGgiLCJqdGkiOiI2ZWJkYjk4MC1iZWM0LTQzMTctOTkwYy1kN2Q3Mzk4MmY3Y2QiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1lQGhlcmUuY29tIiwiaWQiOiIzMjA3YWZkOC1kMTU5LTQwNTgtYmVlNS1kZmRmYzBhYzBlODgiLCJuYmYiOjE1NjM4NzI4ODYsImV4cCI6MTU2Mzg4MDA4NiwiaWF0IjoxNTYzODcyODg2fQ.FGuc5qU-3QoIJBodYf6yi3Wi9Q9RS2kdp0NHaCrplaY"

That seems to show it sent the JWT.

But, I also get a 401 response:

```
date: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 09:12:20 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 status: 401 
 www-authenticate: Bearer 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET 
 x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcU3RvcmFnZVxTb2Z0d2FyZSBSZXBvc2l0b3JpZXNcUGVyc29uYWxcQWNjdUZpbmFuY2VWMkJhY2tlbmRcQWNjdUZpbmFuY2UgQmFja2VuZFxBUElcYXBpXGFjY291bnRz?=
```

I'm not sure how to debug this. I obviously have a code issue somewhere, but can't work out where. The token seems to generate. But fails on validation. Can anyone spot an issue or tell me where I can debug WHY I'm getting the 401?

Comment: I changed your title since this is actually a pretty good description in how to implement a JWT token in .net core

Comment: Thanks @stefan - it’s had 3 close votes unfortunately. Not sure why. But thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are already there, but the `curl` has a typo, change `Authorisation` to `Authorization`:

> curl -X GET "https://localhost:44370/api/accounts" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ.....